# How to use generics to automatically infer types in TS

Tags: typescript

```
function run<U>(func1: (arg: U) => void, func2: (arg: { a: string }) => U): void {}

run((params) => {}, () => 23); // The params here can be correctly inferred as number

run((params) => {}, (arg) => 23); // Why is the params here inferred to be unknown?
```

I want params to automatically infer the correct type in any case

Comment: You've run into [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599).  `arg` needs to be inferred, making `arg => 23` context-sensitive.  The support for this kind of thing implemented at [ms/TS#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538) only works if the inference proceeds left-to-right and not right-to-left. If you refactor to [this version with the args flipped](https://tsplay.dev/mbra2m) then it works. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, this seems to have solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general limitation of TypeScript where it cannot always simultaneously infer [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments and the [contextual type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of some expression, when there is at least syntactically a possibility for these to circularly depend on each other.  TypeScript's inference algorithm does not use so-called "full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science))" as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), so there will always be cases where it fails to infer something you expect.  In those cases you can always just [annotate your callback parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) or manually specify your generic type arguments.

---

In your particular example,  given the call signature

```
function run<U>(func1: (arg: U) => void, func2: (arg: { a: string }) => U): void {}
```

the call to

```
run((params) => {}, () => 23);
```

behaves as desired since `U` can be inferred from the return type of `() => 23`, and since `() => 23` is not *context-sensitive*.  It is known to be of type `() => number` without having to examine the *context* in which it is found.  The callback `(params) => {}` is context sensitive, where `params` is of type `U`. Since `U` is known to be `number`, then `params` is inferred to be of type `number`.

On the other hand, the call to

```
run((params) => {}, (arg) => 23);
```

does not behave as desired. Again, `U` needs to be inferred from the return type of `(arg) => 23`.  But `(arg) => 23` *is* context-sensitive.  Its type depends on the type of `arg` which depends on the context in which the expression is found.  TypeScript decides to *defer* any evaluation here.  Everything breaks down from here; the only other place from which `U` could be inferred is the parameter type of `(params) => {}`, but that's also context sensitive. So nothing can be inferred for `U`. Inference fails, `U` falls back to `unknown`, and `params` is of type `unknown`.

---

Now, of course, the return type of `(arg) => 23` is not *actually* dependent on the type of `arg`, since `23` is a `number` no matter what.  Therefore it should be possible to imagine a compiler improvement which fixes it.  The open feature request [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) is about such cases where the circular dependency is only *apparent*.

And indeed there has been some progress in similar cases.  TypeScript 4.7  introduced [improved function inference in objects and methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538):

> When contextually typing parameters of arrow functions, function expressions, and object literal methods in generic function argument lists, we infer types from *context insensitive* function arguments anywhere in the argument list **and from *context sensitive* function arguments in preceding positions in the argument list.**

That means you should be able to get the inference you want if you rearrange your function parameters so that `U` can be inferred from the *first* argument instead of the *second*. That way the inference can flow from left-to-right instead of right-to-left:

```
function run2<U>(
    func2: (arg: { a: string }) => U,
    func1: (arg: U) => void
): void { }

run2(() => 23, (params) => { },);
//              ^?(parameter) params: number
run2((arg) => 23, (params) => { },);
//                ^?(parameter) params: number
```

That works because even `(arg)=>23` is a context-sensitive function argument that precedes `(params)=>{}`.  Such refactoring isn't always acceptable (e.g., an existing library you can't change), and sometimes there is no refactoring which works (see top paragraph), so it strongly depends on your use case how to proceed in general.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJ3AJgDwFUB8AKAKEWMVEjQC5E8BDZAcyoG9EaqBnKZGMexAXwCUiALw5EWADRESZCAEYqtBlSzCxiAG5wYAEwKCq2vYhb8CBVGDR4868WgDMk6gAc6NALbt7pgZMEAbgIAehCSCMjiAD0Afkt0Wzp6XycXPHdkLx9RcTMA4LCo4pI4oA)